# Mapping List<List<Object>> to a Dictionary with maximum value of object properties

Tags: c#, dictionary, mapping, ienumerable

I have a `List<List<PersonTypeAccess>>`. `PersonTypeAccess` is an object that has 2 properties: `PersonType` and `AccessType`. These are both an enum.

If I try visualizing it, the lists could possibly look like this:

```
{
{ PersonType = 0, AccessType = 2},
{ PersonType = 5, AccessType = 0},
{ PersonType = 2, AccessType = 1}
},
{
{ PersonType = 6, AccessType = 1},
{ PersonType = 3, AccessType = 0}
},
{
{ PersonType = 3, AccessType = 1},
{ PersonType = 5, AccessType = 0},
{ PersonType = 8, AccessType = -1},
{ PersonType = 0, AccessType = 1}
}
```

I need to create a `Dictionary<PersonType, AccessType>` that only has each PersonType once, combined with its highest AccessType value found troughout the lists.

For my example above that would be:

```
{
PersonType 0 -> AccessType 2,
PersonType 8 -> AccessType -1,
PersonType 5 -> AccessType 0,
PersonType 3 -> AccessType 1,
PersonType 6 -> AccessType 1,
PersonType 2 -> AccessType 1
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems have you faced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_SelectMany__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1___) to flatten the lists. You then use [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___2____3__) to group by `PersonType`, where in the result selector you use [`Max`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Max__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32__) on the individual elements (`AccessType` cast to `int`) and select an anonymous type containing each `PersonType` and it's maximum `AccessType`. Finally you project *that* to a dictionary using [`ToDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_ToDictionary__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__).

```
var dict = list
     .SelectMany(c => c)
     .GroupBy(
        c => c.PersonType, 
        c => (int) c.AccessType,
        (key, els) => new { 
           PersonType = key, 
           AccessType = (AccessType)els.Max()
        })
     .ToDictionary(c => c.PersonType, c => c.AcessType);
```